Jack Hales 'Ordinary Differential Equations' as a first text on ODE's?
A few months ago I asked a question on here about comparing Arnold's text and Birkhoff/Rota's text, and the responses pushed me towards Arnold's. However after reading this question ... What is a good text which introduces ODE in a very general setting?, I acquired Jack Hale's book and the style and depth appealed to me greatly and I already have the analysis experience to tackle it.  However, my main concern lies with its coverage of traditional/simpler topics.
For example, many books I've seen have whole chapters dedicated to 'Sturm-Liouville' and the 'Laplace Transform', but there is no mention of these things in Hale's book (unless they're named differently in it).
So, if anyone has read Hale's book and has insight to the breadth of its coverage, and how it would fare as a first text in ODE's, I would greatly appreciate any responses.

Jack Hale’s book is an excellent introduction—pedagogically and with motivating examples—for ODEs, with a target of introducing fundamental stability theory for the initial value problem. Working through this book sets the stage for the next-level treatments of V I Arnold, for example. The author states in his preface that ‘No attempt has been made to cover all aspects of differential equations’ including, for example, Green’s functions and boundary value problems, and, by association, Sturm-Liouville theory. Nor are computational methods and their numerical analysis. These are well-covered by other authors. Enjoy the journey!

Do you know if there are any extremely comprehensive texts that might cover all these topics (although I don't care about dynamical systems coverage, as I intend to read Wiggins dynamical systems book afterwards).
